# Iframe fadeIn()

Tags: jquery, iframe

Hola tengo una imagen y un video en la misma posición con distinto valor de z-index. Quiero hacer fadeOut en la imagen y a la vez fadeIn en el video para hacer una especie de efecto dissolve. No consigo que el fadeIn() se aplique al iframe que contiene el video.

> HTML

```
<div class="imagen-video"></div>

<iframe class="videoContainer__video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ha2f8zU3QP0?modestbranding=1&autoplay=1&controls=0&fs=0&loop=1&rel=0&showinfo=1&disablekb=1&iv_load_policy=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

> CSS

```
.imagen-video{
  background-image: url("../images/img-video.jpg");
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
}

iframe {
  /* optional */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

> JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.imagen-video').fadeOut(500);
    }, 2500);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.videoContainer__video').fadeIn(500);
    },2500);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es el `visibility: hidden` de tu `iframe`. `fadeIn` no cambia la propiedad `visibility`. Según la documentación de jQuery `fadeIn` y `show` son el equivalente a `css('display','block')` por lo que en tu caso no afectaría a `visibility` y seguiría oculto.

> The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation.
>   This is roughly equivalent to calling .css( "display", "block" ),
>   except that the display property is restored to whatever it was
>   initially. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden
>   and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

La diferencia entre `visibility:hidden` y `display:none` es que `visibility:hidden`, aunque no se muestra, sigue ocupando el espacio en pantalla. Aquí más info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Tienes varias opciones para arreglarlo:

1.- Cambiar `visibility:hidden` por `display: none`

2.- Cambiar el atributo `visibility` a `visible` con `css` `$(".videoContainer__video").css('visibility', 'visible');`
Tendrías que aplicarle luego una animación.

3.- Si quieres mantener el espacio que ocupa el `iframe` cambiar primero la propiedad `visibilty`, a continuación ocultarlo con `hide` y luego mostrarlo

```
$('.videoContainer__video').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn(500);
```

Te dejo el fiddle con la primera opción: https://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/o45cr1cu/10/

Comment: La 1º opción no me funciona, pero la 3º si. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Perfecto, si te funciona y te parece buena respuesta, te agredecería que la marcaras como correcta para futuras consultas.

Comment: Lo he hecho, pero me aparece una ventana en azul que me dice que los votos de usuarios con menos de 15 de reputación no aparecen reflejados. Disculpa

Comment: Voto no, hay que seleccionarla como válida

Comment: Listo, no sabia como hacerlo